# EC2 describe-images returns empty data set for windows AMI ami-6a70e303

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

$ aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids ami-6a70e303
{

```
"Images": [],
"ResponseMetadata": {
"RequestId": "348eb2b0-b975-4632-915e-f2e344d275bd"
```

}

From us-east-1.

This ami is for Amazon Windows_Server-2008-R2_SP1-English-64Bit-Base-2013.02.22

Any ideas as to why not returning data ?

Answer (score 0):

This image is apparently deregistered. The command describes images available to you. Being deleted this image is no longer available.

More info here: http://thecloudmarket.com/image/ami-6a70e303--windows-server-2008-r2-sp1-english-64bit-base-2013-02-22#/definition